# _takeLiquidity function does not take effect on Deflationary token

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-20, etherscan, binance

I created a Deflationary token mainly forked from safemoon.
txFee & liqudityFee both 5%.

I suppose every time someone transfers tokens, 5% of it will be burned and 5% go to my token contract. Once the token amount reachs the numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity value. Then swapAndLiquidity will be triggered. This is my understanding and the code is exactly the same as safemoon.

However, I found out no matter how many tokens I transfer by my different addresses. It turns that the token balance in my token contract keeps 0. Shouldn't 5% of the transaction amount be deposited in the token contract for future adding liquidity? Why?
Here is my token address in BSC testnet https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x172ed1f636084523588bb2d13ffddf62c06b8e6f, You could have a look at the transactions if possible. I believe only the contract owner is excluded from the reward. Others are all included in Fee and reward.

I supposed that the _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity) is not taking effect in the _transferStandard() function:

```
function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
    _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
    _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
    _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
    _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
}
```

But how could it happen? Could anyone tell me do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

contract unverified. If you can verify the code on testnet, that would be helpful! It's hard to assume on other code.